# How to sort an array according to another array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I count the words in a paragraph by frequency of occurrences now I need to sort them too for example [this : 2, is : 3, it : 1] to [is : 3, this : 2, it : 1]. I divided keys and values into two different arrays then I sorted an array of values now I want to sort an array of keys

````
console.log('app running');
function getFrequencyOfWord(word : string) {
   let counting: any = {};

   let wordSplit: any = word.split(' ');

   wordSplit.forEach(function (word: any) {

       if (counting[word]) {
               counting[word]++;
       }

       else {
           counting[word] = 1;
       }

       })

       var arr1 = Object.keys(counting);
       var arr2 = arr1.map((suboor)=> {
           return counting[suboor];
       });
       for (var i : number = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
           for (var j = 0; j < (arr2.length -i -1); j++) {

               if (arr2[j] > arr2[j+1]) {
                   const lesser = arr2[j+1];
                   arr2[j+1] = arr2[j];
                   arr2[j] = lesser;
               }
           }
       }

       console.log(arr2);  
       console.log(arr1);

}```
````

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you write the source data as text and desired output as text? –

Comment: @Suboor Khan What happens if some words occur the same number of times.

Comment: [ a : 1, b : 2, c : 2, d : 3] to [d : 3, b : 2, c : 2,  a : 1]

Comment: But I really want to sort the other array from the first array but your code is Superb

Comment: @Suboor Khan Did it answer your question? the thing is that you actually have a map or object instead of an array. An array of objects would be something like `[{is:3},{this:2},{it:1}]` . It's not that difficult to do the conversion.

Comment: @Menios Yes, it does thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
let word = "moo moo moo hello one two three one";
let wordSplit = word.split(' ');
var counting = [];

wordSplit.forEach(function (word) {

    if (counting[word]) {
            counting[word]++;
    }

    else {
        counting[word] = 1;
    }

    })

console.log("Counting ...");console.log(counting);

function swap(json){
  var ret = {};
  for(var key in json){
    let element = ret[json[key]] ;
    //console.log("element");console.log(element);

    if(element == undefined){
      ret[json[key]] = element= [];
    }

    element.push(key);

    //console.log("element");console.log(element);

  }
  return ret;
}

let result = swap(counting);
console.log("RESULT ...");console.log(result);

var finalResult = [];

for(var key in result){
    finalResult = finalResult.concat(result[key]);
 }

console.log("Final RESULT ...");console.log(finalResult);
```

### Output

```
Word Count: 
[moo: 3, hello: 1, one: 2, two: 1, three: 1]

Result: 
{1: Array(3), 2: Array(1), 3: Array(1)}
1: (3) ["hello", "two", "three"]
2: ["one"]
3: ["moo"]

Final Result
0: "hello"
1: "two"
2: "three"
3: "one"
4: "moo"
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/menelaosbgr/xe9u7mqk/33/

### Update

The problem is that you actually have a map of object instead of an array. An array of objects would be something like [{is:3},{this:2},{it:1}] . It's not that difficult to do the conversion. However, I think it's better to have objects that are like this `{word:X, count:x}`. See below:

```
let word = "this this is is it is";

let wordSplit = word.split(' ');

var counting = [];


wordSplit.forEach(function (word) {

    if (counting[word]) {
            counting[word]++;
    }

    else {
        counting[word] = 1;
    }

    })

console.log("Counting ...");console.log(counting);

function swap(json){
  var ret = {};
  for(var key in json){
    let element = ret[json[key]] ;
    //console.log("element");console.log(element);

    if(element == undefined){
      ret[json[key]] = element= [];
    }

    element.push({count:json[key], word:key});

    //console.log("element");console.log(element);

  }
  return ret;
}


let result = swap(counting);
console.log("RESULT ...");console.log(result);


//Reverse it and make it into objects...
let reversedResult = Object.assign([], result ).reverse();
console.log("RESULT-REVERSED ...");console.log(reversedResult); 


//Final Conatenated Array
var concatenatedArray = [];

for(var key in reversedResult){
    concatenatedArray = concatenatedArray.concat(reversedResult[key]);
 }

console.log("CONCATENATED-ARRAY ...");console.log(concatenatedArray);
```

**Result:**

```
0: {count: 3, word: "is"}
1: {count: 2, word: "this"}
2: {count: 1, word: "it"}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/menelaosbgr/xe9u7mqk/49/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to sort array of keys according to array of values but you can do something to map right key to right value by checking if(arr[key] == arr[value]) and if key and value are equal then you can push that key value pair into new array.